# Locate and edit content in Magento 1 block

Tags: magento

I am very new to Magento. I have an old Magento 1 site that someone else has built and I am trying to edit content that is on a particular page, called 'Trade'.

In the backend, I have found the page: CMS > PAGES > TRADE.

The 'CONTENT' tab has some of the pages content written in it, but not the part I want to edit.

The 'DESIGN' tab has the following code, which I believe is where the content I want to edit is located:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="boards" template="cms/trade.phtml" />
</reference>
```

When I go to 'TRADE.PHTML' in my files, I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page');
    $advanced_fields = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($page->getAdvancedFields());
    $cms_fields = array();

    foreach($advanced_fields as $field){
    $name = $field['name'];
        $content = $field['content'];
        $cms_fields[$name] = $content;
    }

    $filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
?>

<div class="board">
    <?php if(isset($cms_fields['board_1'])){ ?>
        <div class="board_left board_inner">
            <?php echo $filter->filter($cms_fields['board_1']); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if(isset($cms_fields['board_2'])){ ?>
        <div class="board_right board_inner">
            <?php echo $filter->filter($cms_fields['board_2']); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I can not for the life of me figure out where to edit this little bit of content, and it's taking up way too much time.

A point in the right direction would be a great help, as I'm sure this is pretty simple and obvious to you Magento devs! Help a newbie out :)

Comment: You forgot to add the part that you are trying to edit (and it is sort of important to your question).  You might benefit from [turning on template hints](https://nwdthemes.com/2016/07/14/magento-1-x-enable-template-path-hints/) to find the files that are being used

Comment: I have mentioned that I don't know where in the backend, the content is for me to edit. I just know that this relates to it:

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="boards" template="cms/trade.phtml" />
    </reference>

When I remove that block from the page (in the backend), it removes the section of content I need to edit. I just don't know where this is pulling the content from.

Comment: "I can not for the life of me figure out where to edit this little bit of **content**" -- what content?